# My discord bot keeps spamming everytime i send a message

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

My goal was to make my bot send a message every time I do, but after I send a message, my bot goes crazy and start spamming messages.

```
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import *
from discord.utils import *


bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("The bot is online")
    await bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=discord.Game('.bothelp'))

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    repeat = True
    while repeat:
        await message.channel.send(f"random text")
        break

bot.run("Bot Token Censored")
```

Comment: You have an endless loop, you never set `repeat` to `False`.

Comment: ```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    repeat = True
    while repeat:
        await message.channel.send(f"random text")
        repeat = False

```
Like this?

Answer (score 1):

You added a break but `on_message` event runs whenever someone sends a message. In this case, bot sends a message and this makes a infinite loop. In order to prevent this, you can check if message author is bot or not. Also, it's meaningless to use a while loop unless you're doing something else than your code in the question.

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.bot:
        return
    await message.channel.send(f"random text")
```